# Inquiry about passing the runtime arguement array into a new class

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, runtime

I am attempting to pass the run time argument array given in the main method to the another class called GPA. I have created the object but I am unsure if How I would send it. Would I use the "this" keyword?

```
 class TestGPA
    {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GPA gpa = new GPA;

        if (args.length == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Please supply grades to find GPA");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            String[] courseIds = new String[args.length];
            char[] grades = new char[args.length];
            parseInput(args, courseIds, grades);
            displayResult(courseIds, grades, computeGPA(grades));
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Write either a custom constructor or a setter that takes a `String[]` for the class `GPA`, if that's what you mean by _argument array given in the main method_

Answer (score 0):

You didn't instantiate `GPA` correctly. it should be:

```
GPA gpa = new GPA();
```

not

```
GPA gpa = new GPA;
```

your `GPA` class could have getter/setter for attributes. for example:

```
//sorry for the indent, didn't write in IDE

class GPA{
 private String[] whatever;

public void setWhatever(String[] w){
  this.whatever = w;
}

public String[] getWhatever(){

return this.whatever;
}

}
```

then in your `main` method, you could

```
GPA gpa = new GPA();
gpa.setWhatever(args);
```

to use the `whatever` attribute:

```
gpa.getWhatever()
```